# Difference in loading time PHP and HTML file?

Tags: php, html, loading

I'm currently working on a website in which some pages are written in PHP, but not all of them.
I'm considering including the menu as a PHP file (so when the menu has to be changed I only have to change it in one file, instead of all my pages). But that requires converting my HTML pages into PHP.

Aside from the fact that changing for example the menus will be easier, will it make a difference in loading time at the clients side?

Just curious if it will make a noticeable difference.

Comment: Short answers is - yes, there will be a difference. Whether is noticeable or not - **you** have to **measure** because there exists no person in this world who can tell you what the difference will be.

Comment: please check this : http://www.differencebetween.info/difference-between-php4-and-php5

Comment: You're more likely to experience excess load times with frontend assets than a basic PHP setup

Comment: A very little, what is really negligible.

Comment: Also notice that, you have not rewrite your html to php. You can configure your web server to parse html as php.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't make any **noticeable** difference unless you add very heavy calculation or bad code inside. For `include` only and maybe some appearances of `if` and `echo` it won't make any difference that you could notice.

Comment: Any drawbacks when using a php file instead of a html? (lets say they have the same content)

Comment: @Lisa drawbacks nothing.. HTML file direct load from path, but `.php` file first process from `PHP` compiler and then provide HTML on client side.

Comment: None I can think of. Both are plain txt files. When server is conifgured to parse html files you don't even have to rewrite their extensions.

Answer (score 1):

The load times will be slightly longer as each of the PHP files needs to be processed in order to generate the HTML which the browser can render. It would also need to load each included file for the page too.

The "slightly longer" won't amount to anything noticeable, it will be fractions of a second for the server to respond.

Answer (score 0):

Will there be difference? Yes.

Noticeable by human? No.